# How to open a URL without launching a new safari tab?

Tags: itunes, terminal, safari, applescript

I would like to write a script (AppleScript or shell script) to open a URL such as

```
https://itunes.apple.com/ca/station/beats-1/idra.978194965
```

which then launches iTunes and play a radio station.

The problem is that all the commands I found will first open a Safari tab and then redirect to iTunes for the playback.

Is there a way to not have an empty Safari tab/window left after launching this URL?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your link with this one:

```
itms://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewRadioStation?id=ra.978194965
```

You can open it without open your safari. Of course, only works with iTunes installed.